# How do I route with query string params in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-router

I have a URL like

> bar?id=foo

If I route to this via `router.push('bar?id=foo')` everything works fine.

But if I go direct to the route in the browser, the query string does not get passed through.

```
const BarComponent = ()=>{
    console.log(useRouter())
}
```

This outputs

```
ServerRouter {
  route: '/bar',
  pathname: '/bar',
  query: {},
  asPath: '/bar',
  basePath: '',
  events: undefined,
  isFallback: false,
  locale: undefined,
  isReady: false,
  locales: undefined,
  defaultLocale: undefined,
  domainLocales: undefined,
  isPreview: false,
  isLocaleDomain: false
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the output you get on the terminal from the server, and shows its default value (`{}`). On the client, you should see 2 console logs: first one with an empty query object (from SSR) and a second one with your query string in it (from rehydration).

`useRouter()` is a React Hook so it'll only run/update on the client.

If you want to have access to the query string on the server-side, you'll need to use `getServerSideProps` and access it through the `query` param from the context object.

```js
export async function getServerSideProps({ query }) {
    console.log(query) // `{ id: 'foo' }`
    //...
}
```

Comment: Abit of a rookie question I guess :(

Comment: Valid question, and often times generates confusion.